# How to merge Feature, Develop and Main without leaving branches ahead/behind (github)

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-squash

We have an issue that whenever we merge into main, develop and main continue to be out of sync.

We have:

- Main - production
- Develop
- stage Feature branches (temporary)

At the start of this, Main and Develop are completely matching (no ahead or behind)

A) Squash and merge

1. Create feature branch from develop
2. Two commits to into branch
3. PR and then squash and merge into develop
4. PR and then squash and merge into main

RESULT: Main ahead 1 and behind 1 vs Develop.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx8Rj.png)

Only way to resolve is to then (a) merge main into develop and then (b) develop into main from CLI without using PR.  I dont want to have to do this extra step and also want settings set to prevent this - I always want the PR.

B) MERGE only

1. Create feature branch from develop
2. Two commits to into branch
3. PR and then merge into develop
4. PR and then merge into main

RESULT: Main ahead 1 vs Develop.  It is ahead because the commit was created by the PR in step 4.
Also, the strange thing is that the PR shows in includes the commits from step (A).

The main issue seems to be that the PRs in themselves create new commits which then can't be copied into the other repo without a PR, which circular issue..

Comment: Either use a rebase merge or use normal merges and copy the commits to the other branch by resetting, cherry-picking or using a fast-forward merge.

Comment: Often, you cannot do this at all through the GitHub web interface. It's easy to do what you need to do using Git (not GitHub!) on your own computer, though.